# What is the significance of the number of orishas?

Tags: africa, yoruba

According to Wikipedia, different oral traditions refer to different numbers of orishas:

> Yoruba tradition often says that there are 401 orishas, which is associated with a sacred number. Other sources suggest that the number is "as many as you can think of, plus one more - an innumerable number". Different oral traditions refer to 400, 700, or 1,440 orisha.
>
> <sub>Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Orisha&oldid=737260447#Number</sub>

Why is 401 sacred to the Yoruba? What is the significance of the other numbers?

Comment: I wish I knew more about this fascinating tradition.  As a referent, I can tell you that 108 is a significant number in Chinese folklore, although it's unclear to what extent the number predates the [Water Margin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/108_Stars_of_Destiny). In Chinese tradition, the number 8 is lucky because the word sounds like the word for prosperity.

Comment: @cybermike Fascinating indeed. You may be interested in taking a look at the Yoruba texts on Sacred Texts: http://www.sacred-texts.com/afr/index.htm#wc_africa

Comment: The Hebraic religions also have an un-numerable numbers for the names of God. I think the numbers are just there to represent "a lot" or "infinity" like here for the (N+1) formula.

Answer (score 3):

There is some information here about why the number 400 is sacred (and the "plus one" probably indicates it being innumerable, i.e. a multitude and one more): [Number of Orishas](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Santeria/DgN8h0GreckC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=number%20of%20orishas&pg=PA45&printsec=frontcover)

[image]

This only answers what the significance of the 401 is, but not the other numbers, sadly.

There are also completely different numbers, here for example [1200 Orishas](https://www.google.com.au/books/edition/Encyclopedia_of_Ancient_Deities/sEIngqiKOugC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=number%20of%20orishas&pg=PA365&printsec=frontcover)

[image]